# how to initialize other view controller scenes?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am learning swift and I have 2 view controller scenes in storyboard.
I could initialize the text of a label in the first scene by adding code

> firstSceneLabel.text = "hello" `in viewedDidLoad(), and it works`

But when I tried to initialize the label in the second scene by adding code

> secondSceneLabel.text = "hello"  `in viewedDidLoad(), I failed`

the system showed: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have 2 questions.

1. Whether I can only initialize elements in first scene by adding codes in viewedDidLoad()?
2. How to initialize elements in the second scene? say secondSceneLabel.text = "hello"

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have 2 different swift class for your scene?

Comment: These 2 scenes share the same class (viewController)

Comment: It is better to use different class for different scene. It found nil is because it cant found 2nd label when viewDidLoad, that why it cannot assign value to it

Comment: thank you! I have already fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I have already fixed this problem.
Thanks to Lee`s suggestion.

I created 1 class for the second scene.
and each class has one viewedDidLoad()
So I can initialize different scenes by add codes in viewedDidLoad() of different classes